# Can't able to add clustered node IP in Mongos

Tags: mongodb, database-administration, sharding

I'm a beginner at Mongodb. so I trying to configure the sharding in MongoDB. so I have 2 separate server with Linux centos OS and installed MongoDB 4.2.24 version in both servers so initially there is no Mongos.conf file present in etc. but Mongod.conf file is available so I created a Mongos.conf file with the below code:

systemLog:
destination: file
path: /var/log/mongos/mongos.log
processManagement:
fork: true
net:
bindIp: localhost
port: 27017
sharding:
configDB: configdb_server1:27017,configdb_server2:27017,configdb_server3:27017

then I tried to execute this below command:

mongos -f /path/to/mongos.conf

I getting this error: FailedToParse: invalid url [172.28.129.131:27017,172.28.136.157:27017]
try 'mongos --help' for more information again and again getting same error tell me the proper way so I need to add my second server IP in mongos for enabling sharding so need help here.

Comment: looks like you are missing the replica set name in the configdb setting. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-sharding.configDB

Comment: @Joe is needs to set replication initially for sharding ?

Comment: yes, the config server replica set must be a replica set